# For-each group in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to use for-each group in XSLT 1.0 which is quite comfortable in XSLT 2.0.
However my application expects  XSLT 1.0.
Also some additional input text in the XML

Input XML of XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<message:GenericData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:generic="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/generic"
 xmlns:message="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/message"
 xmlns:common="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/common">
<message:Header>
    <message:ID>BBSDI</message:ID>
    <message:Test>false</message:Test>
    <message:Prepared>2023-06-30T10:18:43.607+02:00</message:Prepared>
    <message:Sender id="BBK">
        <common:Name xml:lang="de">Deutsche Bundesbank</common:Name>
        <message:Contact>
            <message:Email>presse-information@bundesbank.de</message:Email>
        </message:Contact>
    </message:Sender>
    <message:Structure structureID="BBK_SEDI" dimensionAtObservation="TIME_PERIOD">
        <common:Structure>
            <URN>urn:sdmx:org.sdmx.infomodel.datastructure.DataStructure=BBK:BBK_SEDI(1.0)</URN>
        </common:Structure>
    </message:Structure>
</message:Header>
        <message:DataSet structureRef="BBK_SEDI" >
            <generic:Series> 
                <generic:SeriesKey>  
                    <generic:Value id="BBK_SEDI_CALCULATION" value="ABZINS7"></generic:Value>        
                </generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id="BBK_ID" value="BBSDI.M.ABZINS7.R01"></generic:Value>
                </generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Obs>
                    <generic:ObsDimension value="2015-01"></generic:ObsDimension>
                    <generic:ObsValue value="3.07"></generic:ObsValue>
                </generic:Obs>
                <generic:Obs>
                    <generic:ObsDimension value="2016-01"></generic:ObsDimension>
                    <generic:ObsValue value="3.05"></generic:ObsValue> 
                </generic:Obs>
            </generic:Series>
            <generic:Series>
                <generic:SeriesKey>       
                    <generic:Value id="BBK_SEDI_CALCULATION" value="ABZINS7"></generic:Value>                       
                </generic:SeriesKey>
                <generic:Attributes>
                    <generic:Value id="BBK_ID" value="BBSDI.M.ABZINS7.R02"></generic:Value>
                </generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Obs>
                    <generic:ObsDimension value="2015-01"></generic:ObsDimension>
                    <generic:ObsValue value="1.07"></generic:ObsValue>
                </generic:Obs>
                <generic:Obs>
                    <generic:ObsDimension value="2016-01"></generic:ObsDimension>
                    <generic:ObsValue value="1.05"></generic:ObsValue>
                </generic:Obs> 
            </generic:Series>
        </message:DataSet>
    </message:GenericData>
```

Using XSLT 2.0 which is running quite well, it seems my application is not supporting XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/generic">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns1:DiscountInterestRatePercent xmlns:xslt-version="MonthlyDiscounts_XSLT_26/06/2022">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//Series[SeriesKey/Value/@value='ABZINS7']/Obs" group-by="ObsDimension/@value">
            <Data>
                <Year>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(current-grouping-key(), '-')"/>
                </Year>
                <Month>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(current-grouping-key(), '-')"/>
                </Month>
                <RatePercentList>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <RatePercent>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ObsValue/@value"/>
                        </RatePercent>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </RatePercentList>
            </Data>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ns1:DiscountInterestRatePercent>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to use this logic in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For XSLT 1.0 you need to use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

You'll notice it's fairly similar, you're just using xsl:key and key() instead of xsl:for-each-group...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:g="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/generic"
    xmlns:m="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/message"
    exclude-result-prefixes="g m">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="obs" match="g:Obs" use="g:ObsDimension/@value"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/*/m:DataSet">
        <DiscountInterestRatePercent xmlns:xslt-version="MonthlyDiscounts_XSLT_26/06/2022">
            <xsl:for-each select="g:Series/g:Obs[count(.|key('obs',g:ObsDimension/@value)[1])=1]">
                <xsl:variable name="obsdim" select="g:ObsDimension/@value"/>
                <Data>
                    <Year>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($obsdim,'-')"/>
                    </Year>
                    <Month>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($obsdim,'-')"/>
                    </Month>
                    <RatePercentList>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('obs',$obsdim)">
                            <RatePercent>
                                <xsl:value-of select="g:ObsValue/@value"/>
                            </RatePercent>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </RatePercentList>
                </Data>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </DiscountInterestRatePercent>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nzb5jQ

Note: I didn't do any filtering based on `ABZINS7` and I didn't bother with namespaces in the output. Those are left up to the reader.

Comment: Hello Daniel,

Thank you for the code, Filter is also must needed.

Comment: @Sateesh - That should be easy for you to add; you had it in the original XSLT. This was only to demonstrate muenchian grouping; not to give you 100% complete code for free.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your suggestion.
I tried to filter the way, some how filter is not working this way.
<xsl:for-each 
select="g:Series[g:SeriesKey/g:Value/@value='ABZINS7']/generic:Obs[count(.|key('obs',generic:ObsDimension/@value)[1])=1]">

More inputs would help

Comment: @Sateesh Please study the code and the literature on Muenchian grouping; don't try to run the code or modify it until you understand it. It's not easy to understand compared with the XSLT 2.0 feature but there are good tutorials. Also, perhaps it's time to find an XSLT processor that supports XSLT 2.0? It will make your life much easier.

Comment: @Sateesh - Like Dr. Kay said, it's important to understand how Muenchian grouping works. Not only do you need to update the select in the xsl:for-each, you also need to update the xsl:key. See the updated fiddle here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nzb5jQ/1

Comment: Hi Daniel, Hi Michael, you people are supporting like a god in the code for us. you made many lives easier in the job life. Really awesome support from you like people.

Comment: Hi Daniel,

If it be possible, I am looking for another fix in this where I have also addtional header in the put which I didn't added initially but now it cause the issue with this code.

I just updated my initial my input again, if you could able to help me to fix this  it would be good for me. I tried to fix by myself but not resolved yet.

Comment: @Sateesh - Once a question has an accepted answer, the question shouldn't be modified; a new question should be asked. This was a simple fix so here's just an updated fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nzb5jQ/2

Comment: Thank you  Daniel. will  make sure next time